# Mongo db 3.6 and case sensitive field names

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Are field names case sensitive in Mongodb 3.6? Is there a way they might have been case-insensitive on 3.4 and sensitive on 3.6? I have a query that should be failing on 3.4, but it works. A field named

foo_id

in my query is also matching for

foo_Id

very strange? Or not?

Thanks. Using mongodb 3.6 and mongoose 4.13.15. I did also upgrade to this version of Mongoose, I was at 4.9 when things seem to be very case insensitive.

Comment: I also have same question , I am using mongoDB atlas on cloud , it allows to create duplicate fields if casing is different, my question is WHY ? Is there any special Use Case ?

Comment: MongoDB documentation is silent on the case sensitivity of field names.  It is baffling that this oversight in documentation has not been corrected in years.